# Is the use of the word inspite right in this context?

Tags: word-usage

This is a notice drafted by one of my lawyer, which I think has an opposite meaning compared to how it should be. Just a bit of context- someone (a fraud couple) didn't pay me money for a property they purchased from me, instead they claimed that they have paid the money and filed a case against me. So I had a complaint written against these fraud persons through my lawyer, but kindly read the following underlined sentence. To my dumb brain it feels like it means that I was actually paid full money, I am not sure of the use of the word in this context at all!

> ... But inspite of the payment of full consideration amount the lady XXX XXXXX XXXXX had initiated a criminal case comprised of fraud, concocted, frivolous and baseless statements...

[image]

PS- As this a letter related to law, I was wondering whether the word 'inspite' means something different there.

Answer (score 1):

### I am not a lawyer and I do not know the legal implications of this language.

There are numerous grammatical errors in that text. *Inspite* is not a word; it's two words *in spite*.

But if we make it two words, it does appear that the statement says something like, "Even though someone paid the full amount, the lady initiated a criminal case."

This is a logically consistent statement, but it does not reflect the reality of the situation as described in the original post. No amount was paid, and a criminal case was initiated.

Perhaps the author of the statement meant "in spite of **not** paying the full amount, the buyer initiated a criminal case..."

Answer (score 0):

The letter was written by someone not highly skilled in English and contains numerous errors.

In the highlighted section, The spelling "inspite" is an error, the correct spelling is "in spite". The use of "consideration amount" is incorrect: You can pay the full amount, or you can talk about the consideration in a contract.  The punctuation is poor and that makes it harder to read.

However, the meaning seems to be clear.  Even though the lady received the full amount of money that she was due according to the contract, she still started a criminal case against "me". To paraphrase:

> The lady got her money, but she still reported me to the police.